UPBGE blender scripts are not reflecting changes in viewport when applied?
Changing variables or functions within the blender scripts should normally be auto updated. I wanted to select a face on the plane added to scene and extrude it for several units. At the beginning no problem but when I change the face index then it does not update this condition. I did make several changes in my blender script and hoped Blender would auto update this and show me the updated result in my view port. I tried "Reloading script" or went to blender->system->reload and tried it again, but no luck, it could not update my script. Below is a screen shot and the code:
I researched on internet and saw that it should be a problem for many people, but could not reason why exactly. Could you help me out? I am new in Blender and do not want to hang on problems which have maybe easy explanation.
import bpy
import bmesh

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode( type = 'FACE' )

plane = bpy.context.scene.objects['Plane'].data

bm = bmesh.new()

bm.from_mesh(plane)

#bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)

bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

for face in bm.faces:
    face.select = False

bm.faces[42].select = True
    
#bm.faces.active = bm.faces[10]

bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_faces_move(TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten={"value":+10})

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

#bm.to_mesh(plane)



Edit:
I have a working code:
import bpy
import bmesh

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode( type = 'FACE' )

plane = bpy.context.scene.objects['Plane'].data

bm = bmesh.new()

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(plane)

#bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)

bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

for face in bm.faces:
    face.select = False

bm.faces[19].select = True
    
#bm.faces.active = bm.faces[10]

bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_faces_move(TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten={"value":+10})

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(plane)

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()


Now it is working like expected.


Instead of adding your solution as an 'edit" session, you can post it as an answer to your own question.
Later on you will be able to aprove your own answer to the question - that is a perfectly valid usage of this site, and will keep things in place (questions as questions and answers as answers)
